# Disable battery

Tags: battery, atom

I installed linux manjaro on Lenovo Miix 320 (Atom x5 z8350) and got mostof it to work except for the battery indicator. It shows 100% all the time, but that is not the problem. The problem is when I shut down or restart the computer, then it gets stuck in some loop and print this all the time:

```
axp288_fuel_gauge acp288_fuel_gauge: capacity measurement not valid
axp288_fuel_gauge acp288_fuel_gauge: driver failed to report "charge_now" propery -6
```

Can I fix or disable the drivers from triggering all this battery related stuff?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no software/configuration or other trick that would do what you want just because laptops are designed so. To force it to using AC you have to take the battery out, which, as a side effect, also increases the life of the battery due to reduced warming (given that you store the battery in an appropriate place).